# message passing happens twice if "run_at" : "document_start" is used in chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

In my extension, I am passing a message from background.js to contentScript.js.

The issue is that when I use

```
"run_at" : "document_start"
```

in my manifest.json, the message from background.js to contentScript.js is called twice and sometimes even more than that.

Message passing more than once is a bit expensive in my case as I'm sending a call to server and the processing the same values at the server multiple times is expensive.

background.js

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) { 

   chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {type: "get-url", url: tab.url});

});
```

contentScript.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(   
  function(message, sender, sendResponse) { 
    switch(message.type) {
    case "get-url" : someFunction(message.url); 
                     break;
            // other cases

    }
});
```

Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: In order to track down the issue that is causing the second message, we need to see some code, don't we ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[`chrome.tabs.onUpdated`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#event-onUpdated)** is called multiple times in the tab-update cycle (e.g. when the tab starts loading the new page, when the tab completes loading the new page, when the favicon is fetched etc).

The best option is to checj for when the tab has completed loading:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId, info, tab) {
    if (info.status === 'complete') {
        /* Now it is safe to send the message */
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, {
            type: 'get-url',
            url:  tab.url
        });
    }
});
```

---

BTW, when injecting programmatically (not in `manifest.json`), the property's name is `runAt`, not `run_at` (**[docs](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#type-InjectDetails)**).

Comment: Is this different from checking if DOM has loaded?

Comment: If you have the content-script injected at `document_start` and send the message when the tab's status is `loading`, I am not sure if it is guaranteed that it will reach its receipient. What exactly are your requirements (i.e. when do you want your script to run) ?

Comment: I want to send the message to content-script as soon as I have the url of the current tab. When does tab completes loading? is it after the DOM has loaded? or before it?

Comment: Will the content script be injected into that tab or another ?

Comment: Then why don't you grab the URL right from within the content-script ?? (E.g. `window.location.href`)

Comment: Always glad to help ! (Feel free to also upvote the answer if you really liked it ;))